# how to get an instance of CommonDao in DBUtil

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I have a specific requirement.
I have a Controller rest endpoint which is called by Scheduler and Job details are provided to the Controller.
In order for it to be Async, i spawn a new Thread from my Contoller end point to execute the Job and simultaneously the response is send back to the Scheduler.
I have created a class JobExecutor which extends Thread.

Edit - JobExecutor would extend Runnable.

Before i start the new Thread, i set the job in it like below,

```
JobExecutor jobExecutor = new JobExecutor();
jobExecutor.setJob(job); // Job received through Scheduler
jobExecutor.start();
```

In the run() method, i am using Quartz api to execute the Job.
I have created a custom class CustomJob implements Job(of Quartz API)

In the execute() method of CustomJob,i am using a ScriptExecutor class which is in the COMMON module.

```
ScriptExecutor scriptExecutor = new ScriptExecutor();
scriptExecutor.execute(job);
```

In the execute() method of ScriptExecutor, i use ProcessBuilder to execute the Job.

After the execution is started, i have to insert into Oracle Database.
For that i have a DbUtil class which makes use of CommonDao to insert into Database.
I create an instance of DbUtil using new in ScriptExecutor class

```
class DbUtil
@Autowired
CommonDao   // DOES NOT WORK

@Repository
class CommonDao implements JPARepository
```

ScriptExecutor, DbUtil and CommonDao are all part of the COMMON module.

In the COMMON module, i have a TransactionConfig class which has the DataSource, EntityManager and
TransactionManager beans defined.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJPARepository(dao package)
@EntityScan(model package)
class TransactionConfig
```

How could i get the instance of CommonDao in DbUtil ?
I tried Autowiring, but since DbUtil is not a bean or Component, it doesnt work.

Many Threads would access the DbUtil and CommonDao at the same time to Update or Insert into Database, so it has to be Thread safe as well.

Comment: What do you think dependency injection means?

Comment: Don't create threads yourself, create a task and schedule/execute that using a `TaskExecutor` don't create threads yourself. If you do the latter you can simply use dependency injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for the suggestion. I would use Executor Framework to execute the Threads that i would spawn.

Comment: Don't. Don't create threads yourself, reuse pooled threads instead and let the framework handle it for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Yes...you are correct. Would implement Runnable and pass to the Executor Framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, by setting the Application Context in the Runnable and then passing it along till the ScriptExecutor class and then i used the Application Context to set the CommonDao bean in the DbUtil instance.